# Custom DisplayName for Parent Object's same property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model class that has a property of the same type (to create a hierarchy):

```
public class OrganizationalChart : Model
{
    public Guid? ParentId { set; get; }
    public virtual OrganizationalChart Parent { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

In my `Razor` view file:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parent.Name)
```

Both lines obviously print `Name`. Situation is the same when I use `[Display(Name="Role Name")]`.

My desired functionality is to be able set different Display names for `Name` property of current object and the `Name` property of parent object.

Is there a way to do this without using custom `HTML` tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no way to override the display name on a child instance. However, depending on your use case, there may be options. For example, if you're using `Html.LabelFor`, it takes a parameter that allows you to specify the label text:

```
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Name)
@Html.LabelFor(modelItem => item.Parent.Name, "Parent Name")
```

`Html.DisplayNameFor` doesn't make sense to use in this context, because all it does is just output a simple string (the display name). As a result, there's not any "custom HTML"; you can just hard-code the name you would like. `Html.DisplayFor` doesn't display the property name at all, so I'm not sure what you're expecting with that.